# jqxGrid is not populating from PHP-generated JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jqxgrid

Facing a problem today, that jqxGrid shows : No data to display.

Downloaded and unpacked today v7.1.0.

1. Testing with browser Mozilla
2. Here is JSON, which generated by API:

{"data":[{"id":46,"dateChanged":"2019-03-02 06:30:42","isHidden":0,"isBusiness":0,"name1":"System","name2":"Administrator","sex":0,"dateOfBirth":"1970-01-01"},{"id":47,"dateChanged":"2019-03-02 06:49:25","isHidden":0,"isBusiness":0,"name1":"System 1","name2":"Administrator 1","sex":1,"dateOfBirth":"1980-01-01"}]}

3. Here is code, exactly as shown in demo in order to populate grid:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jqxdata.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jqxgrid.pager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/AA/assets/jqx/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var customerSource =
                    {
                        datatype: 'json',
                        datafields: [
                            {name: 'id'},
                            {name: 'name1'},
                            {name: 'name2'}
                        ],
                        id: 'id',
                        url: '/api/customer/get/list',
                        root: 'data'
                    };

            var customerAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(customerSource,
                    {
                        formatData: function (data) {
                            return {};
                        }
                    }
            );

            customerAdapter.dataBind();

            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
                    {
                        source: customerAdapter,
                        columnsresize: true,
                        autoheight: true,
                        autowidth: true,
                        columns: [
                            {text: 'id', datafield: 'id', width: 180},
                            {text: 'First Name', datafield: 'name1', width: 180},
                            {text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'name2', width: 180}
                        ]
                    });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
</body>
```

Am I doing something wrong or shall i use another library?

Thank You,
Roman.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, problem was in PHP generating JSON. I didn't noticed earlier but it adds to URI some parameters that was not processed correctly. Fixed by changing the PHP generating JSON script!